Elliptical Grid Mapping in Shader

I wanted to make a Elliptical Grid Mapping Shader, but it is not a perfect square and it is rotated.
If i multiply the coords by sqrt(2.) and divides them after again, it is an square, but still rotated...
Why is it like this?
I used the maths from here.
Code with Sqrt(2.) added:
vec2 trCircToSquare(vec2 p){
p=(p-0.5)*2.*sqrt(2.);
    return 0.5/sqrt(2.)*(vec2(
        0.5*sqrt( 2.+p.x*p.x-p.y*p.y+2.*p.x*sqrt(2.))-0.5*sqrt(2.+p.x*p.x-p.y*p.y - 2*p.x*sqrt(2.)),
        0.5*sqrt( 2. + p.y*p.y - p.x*p.x + 2.*p.y*sqrt(2.) ) - 0.5* sqrt( 2. + p.y*p.y - p.x*p.x - 2*p.y*sqrt(2.) )
        ))+0.5;
        

}

out vec4 fragColor;
void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture(sTD2DInputs[0], trCircToSquare(vUV.st));
    
    fragColor = TDOutputSwizzle(color);
}


